# PHP: Реализация полей абстрактного класса

Tags: php, php7

В проекте необходимо работать с денежными единицами. Изначально я использовал пакет [MoneyPHP](https://moneyphp.org/en/stable/). Некоторые его функции оказались очень неудобными. Так или иначе я начал создавать к ним обертки и в какой-то момент понял, что обертки почти полностью заменяют сам пакет. В процессе их создания я неплохо так поупражнялся в ООП. Не долго думая, решил от пакета избавиться и дописать необходимые решения, создав тем самым свой полноценный сервис. Все очень удачно. Структура всплыла сама собой. Но возникла проблема.

При работе с денежными единицами необходимо указывать их валюту. В пакете [MoneyPHP](https://moneyphp.org/en/stable/) валюта выделяется в отдельную сущность (final class Currency). По сути, в себе она содержит только валютный код. В своем проекте я столкнулся с необходимостью использования минорных денежных единиц. То есть 1 рубль должен быть равен 100 копейкам. В пакете это реализовано, но реализовано криво. Объект валюты в себе не содержит данные о кратности. Пакет предлагает создавать денежную единицу, как:

```
$money = Money::RUB(100); // 1 RUB
```

Эта запись равносильна:

```
$currency = new Currency("RUB");
$money = new Money(100, $currency); // 1 RUB
```

Всё вроде бы хорошо и до поры удобно. Но... Проблема в том, что я каждый раз должен указывать размер создаваемой денежной единицы. То есть если я хочу получить 1 единицу любой валюты, то я должен знать размер её подвалюты и указать размер в ней. Я не могу просто прописать:

```
$money = Money::RUB;
```

И получить 1 рубль, равный 100 единицам. Это очень неудобно. Поэтому я решил сделать финальный класс "final class Currency" абстрактным классом "abstract Currency" и реализовывать его в конкретных классах-валютах. То есть вот так:

```
abstract class Currency implements CurrencyContract
{
    private string $code;
    private int $unit;

    ...
}

final class RUB extends Currency
{
    public const code = "RUB";
    public const unit = 100;
}
```

Проблема возникла в недостаточности знания языка. Я создал интерфейс, описывающий что должна делать валюта. Я описал что она должна иметь. Я создал реализующий её класс, содержащий значения конкретной валюты. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как передать значения констант из реализующего класса в класс-родитель. Как мне передать мои const code и const unit из класса RUB в класс Currency чтоб записать их в $code и $unit?

Comment: Если честно, то я ничего не понял. И с самого начала, но особенно в части " как передать значения констант из реализующего класса в класс-родитель", да ещё и абстрактный к тому же.

Comment: По-простому. Когда я создаю объект RUB, то в нем есть константы. Эти константы я хочу записать в поля, наследуемые из класса Currency. И прописать этот механизм в классе Currency.

Comment: Но зачем прописывать что-то в абстрактном классе? Зачем вообще вызывать методы **абстрактного** класса? у тебя есть класс РУБ - ну вот к нему и обращайся. Вообще, как я понимаю, все проблемы происзодят от статики. Если бы здесь были нормальные объекты, то и проблем бы не было, а был бы объект $currency, который, используя полиморфизм, и прнедставлял собой нужную валюту

Comment: Затем, чтоб его методы были унаследованы дочерними классами и работали со значениями в них записанными. Класс RUB не абстрактный. 
Можно было бы сделать трейт. Но это тупость.

Comment: Ну вот и используй дочерний класс РУБ. проблема решена

Comment: Так я и буду его использовать. Я же не собираюсь создавать объект от абстрактного класса. В нем используются свойства, значения которых прописаны в наследниках. В шарпе они передаются элементарно через конструктор абстрактного класса и метод :base()  в дочернем. Тут этого насколько я знаю нет. Но реализацию того что я хочу - видел. Только разобрать не могу. Поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Используйте тот же конструктор и [parent()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php) вместо base().